# Low hour Pilot wants to move up to Piper Malibu Mirage but having trouble finding insurance

Tags: general-aviation, insurance

I am a 350 hour instrument rated pilot and current. I own and fly a Piper Saratoga II TC and I am rated for complex, high performance, retractable wheel airplanes. I have approximately 150 hours in the PA 32. Current age 59.

I want to move up to a FIKI factory installed airplane and have been mentored that perhaps the PA 46 Piper Malibu Mirage would be a great next step.

Having issues with companies willing to insure me even though my Saratoga has similar systems just not quite as fast. Any suggestions from anyone on what I can do except fly more hours to get insurance?

Comment: Have you contacted the aopa?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I'm not sure what you're asking here. Insurance companies set their own requirements to act as PIC if you want their insurance; if you don't like what they're proposing then of course you can negotiate (e.g. agree to fly more hours with a CFI before flying solo) or look for another company (perhaps using a specialized aviation insurance broker).

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to get around the time-in-type requirement for insurance. That's pretty much a set-in-stone requirement, especially for a high performance aircraft like the Mirage. I suggest that while you build the hours you fly with someone who meets the requirements for insurance.

Comment: Thanks. So far I’m being told that I need 750-1000 hours. Seems excessive. I have not contacted AOPA as yet will see if they have some suggestions.

Comment: That would be total time, not time in type. I am not surprised. Shop around for other insurance and talk to AOPA, but I don't think the requirement will drop that much.